# How to query an MSSQL database

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008

[image]

Figure 01 is a table in database, and I want to extract the data as shown in Figure 02.

Which query should I use?

Unique elements in Col_1 should become the column name for new table and elements in Col_2 should become the values as shown in Figure 02.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function along with `row_number()` to get the result:

```
select A, B
from
(
  select col_1, col_2,
    row_number() over(partition by col_1 order by col_2) rn
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(col_2)
  for col_1 in (A, B)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c156/4).

Or you can use an aggregate function with a CASe expression to convert the rows into columns:

```
select 
  max(case when col_1 = 'A' then col_2 end) A,
  max(case when col_1 = 'B' then col_2 end) B
from
(
  select col_1, col_2,
    row_number() over(partition by col_1 order by col_2) rn
  from yourtable
) d
group by rn;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c156/5)